# The name of something close to a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a sample set of data similar to the the one depicted in following picture
[frequency response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc6UI.png)

I have taken the rate of change for each point in the data set as show below.

(1)   $\quad (f_2-f_1)/(t_2-t_1) = df/dt$

What I am actually after is the rate of change of each point relative to the first point $(t_0=0).$

(2) $\quad (f_2-f_0)/(t_2-t_0)$

My problem is that when I plot the second dataset (2) I dont know what to call it .  The first equation (1) is a derivative of the dataset but I dont know what the second one (2) should be called.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @viciouskinid The derivative is the *limit* of this rate, not the rate itself. In both (1) and (2) you would obtain the same limit (if it exists).